# Prevent installation of BOTH PostgreSQL 9.1 and 9.2

Tags: ubuntu, debian, postgis, puppet, apt

In an attempt to automate the deployment of an Ubuntu 12.04 server (using Puppet) that contains Postgresql 9.2 and PostGIS 2.x, I end up with both PostgreSQL 9.1 and 9.2 installed and their services both started on ports 5432 and 5433.

Why does this happen even though I installed only `postgresql-9.2`? How can the problem be fixed?

**Installation Procedure**

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.2 postgresql-server-dev-9.2 postgresql-client-9.2 postgresql-contrib-9.2 postgis

apt-get install libxml2-dev, libjson0-dev, xsltproc, docbook-xsl, docbook-mathml, gettext, libgeos-3.2.2, libgeos-c1, libgeos-dev, proj, geos, pg_top
```

---

**repo:**

```
ppa:pitti/postgresql
ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
```

**apt-cache show postgis**

```
Package: postgis
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 2917
Maintainer: Debian GIS Project <pkg-grass-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 2.0.1-2~precise3
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libgdal1 (>= 1.9.0), libgeos-c1 (>= 3.3.3), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.14.0), libpq5, postgresql-9.1-postgis
Filename: pool/main/p/postgis/postgis_2.0.1-2~precise3_amd64.deb
Size: 889350
MD5sum: 243ef9b2668417391a4d911024b43260
SHA1: 3588bca6e15f6bbb6e2c478d33da424a1fc8da77
Description-en: Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL -- common files
 PostGIS adds support for geographic objects to the PostgreSQL object-relational
 database. In effect, PostGIS "spatially enables" the PostgreSQL server,
 allowing it to be used as a backend spatial database for geographic information
 systems (GIS), much like ESRI's SDE or Oracle's Spatial extension. PostGIS
 follows the OpenGIS "Simple Features Specification for SQL".
 .
 This package contains the PostGIS userland binaries, common files and
 documentation.
```

**apt-cache policy**

```
postgis:
  Installed: 2.0.1-2~precise3
  Candidate: 2.0.1-2~precise3
  Version table:
 *** 2.0.1-2~precise3 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.5.3-2 0
        500 http://ubuntu.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: `apt-cache show postgis` and `apt-cache policy postgis`? Same for `postgresql-9.2`? At a guess you're using a 3rd pty repo for `postgresql-9.2` that doesn't include PostGIS or has it under a different name, so you're getting a version of PostGIS that depends on PostgreSQL 9.1. What repos do you have configured?

Comment: Updated post with the `apt-cache` details. Looks like `postgis` has `postgresql-9.1` as a dependency. How should we work around that?

Comment: You'll need to find a packaging of PostgreSQL 9.2 that has PostGIS available as part of the repo or you'll need to compile PostGIS yourself against the Pg 9.2 you have installed. (BTW, if you don't @ reply me I don't get notified of your comment, I only saw that you'd replied by chance).

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks didnt know about the notifications with `@` replies. I believe `checkinstall` should be the quickest way to create the package?

Comment: It would be interesting to know what `postgresql-9.1-postgis` contains, and what it depends on.  Probably PostGIS is very easily ported to PostgreSQL 9.2.